# Linear Algebra Done Wrong Ch 1 Exercise 6.2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I recently started the book "Linear Algebra Done Wrong" and in chapter 1, I came across this question "Find all right inverses to the 1 × 2 matrix (row) A = (1, 1). Conclude from
here that the row A is not left invertible." In this case what exactly is the identity because he only defines the identity matrix for $n \times n$ matrices. And if there is no identity then what does it mean to find an inverse (or in this case right inverse) for matrices that are not square.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It means find all 2 by 1 matrices (column vectors) $v=\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\v_2\end{pmatrix}$ such that $(1,1)v=1.$

Comment: The identity matrix must have $1$ row because it is equal to
$(1,1)A$ for the right inverse $A$. So the identity matrix is just $(1)$, the right inverse must be a $2\times1$ matrix $(a,b)^T$, otherwise the product $(1,1)A$ is not defined or is not a $1\times 1$.
So all right inverses are matrices $(a,b)^T$ satisfying $a+b=1$.

Comment: Of course the exercise makes little sense because it is not clear where all these matrices are from and how to multiply them if they have non-matching dimensions. But I guess this is the fault of the author, Sergei Treil.

Comment: Previously in the book (6.2) the right inverse of a linear transformation $A \colon V \to W$ is defined to be a linear transformation $C: W \to V$ such that $AC = I_W$ (meaning the identity operator on $W$). In the land of matrices we don't really keep track of $V$ and $W$ per se, only their dimensions. So if $A$ is a $1 \times 2$ matrix, a right inverse $C$ should be a $2 \times 1$ matrix, such that $AC = [1]$ where $[1]$ is a $1 \times 1$ matrix.